# SPField_FormDisplay_Default is not defined

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

I have set JSLink to a field (`LinkFilename`) that required to return default rendering in some context.

I implementation according [PnP/ReadOnlySPControls.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Branding.ClientSideRendering/Branding.ClientSideRenderingWeb/Scripts/JSLink-Samples/ReadOnlySPControls.js), and use `SPField_FormDisplay_Default` to render default value.

But this seems not working in my environment and says '**SPField_FormDisplay is not defined**'.

Any Idea?

Here is my JSLink code:

```
(function () {

    function renderLinkFilename(renderCtx) {
        var fieldCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(renderCtx);
        return SPField_FormDisplay_Default(renderCtx);
    }

    function registerRender() {
        var ctxView = {};
        ctxView.Templates = {};
        ctxView.Templates.Fields = { "LinkFilename": { "View": renderLinkFilename } };

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxView);
    }

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRender, 'clienttemplates.js');
})();
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more on what you are trying to accomplish. What form/webpart did you try this code on?

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to intercept ``onclick`` event (ex. ``DispEx``) on list items and make it call my custom method. I used to customize by adding ``fldtypes_myproduct.xsl`` in SharePoint 2010, but it does not work after the migration to 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According my inspection, I can use `ComputedFieldWorker.LinkFilenameNoMenu(listItem, listSchema)` to render default value.

And the implementation can be found in *C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clienttemplates.debug.js*